# Running first Kotlin example in Android Studio with failure

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am new to Android development and created my first Android Studio project (Empty Activity type).
However when I am presented with the following error message:

5:09 PM Gradle sync failed: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.6.21', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.6.21')
Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository
Google
MavenRepo (9 s 311 ms)

I am running Windows 10 and have no clue how to resolve this. Can anybody provide some input?

thanks

Comment: The build.gradle file looks like this: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

And indeed I did not change anything, just created a new project.

Comment: Actually, it should have no problem with that. Plugins are pulled from the Gradle plugin repo without you having to specify it. Try clicking the Terminal tab at the bottom of the screen and entering `gradlew build` to see if it works that way. Then try the Build menu -> Clean Project.